# Mounting a tmp folder

Tags: mount

I was trying to install some libraries into R. However, the R could not write anything into /tmp folder so it actually failed the library installation. I found this advice:

```
mount -o remount,exec /tmp
```

What does this do? I read that **mount** should add the detached partitions into the file tree. But /tmp is already in my file system, isn't it? Why do I have to attach it anywhere? And what is remount?

Comment: On an ordinary Ubuntu installation, `/tmp` is an ordinary folder. You don't need to mount it. It should have permissions `drwxrwxrwt` and be owned by root.

Comment: @Jos, even though i have root there, R does not write to that folder under sudo. Only mount helps. I have not tried manually chmod, but it is a server, so maybe I do not want to open tmp for everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible that for security reasons, `/tmp` is a specific filesystem and is mounted with `noexec`, to prevent executing any file that is on `/tmp`. The command above would remount `/tmp` without the `noexec`, allowing the execution of files.

This said, on my Ubuntu, `/tmp` is in `/` so is not a filesystem by itself.

You have likely been given an incorrect answer. Is the question asked on the SE network?

Comment: No, I just found this solution on the internet somewhere - probably in SE network (cannot find the QA anymore). The filesystem is located on the server. However, I have not actually tried to change the access using chmod, since I was originally executing R with sudo, and it still did not allow writing into /tmp, so I guessed the mount option was the right one, though i do not understand how it works (it does).